# Node.js - Serving file for download using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I am creating an endpoint that serves a file generated dynamically. I have written a controller which generates the file after certain operation based on request param `fileId`.

I am throwing some errors if anything goes wrong while file generation or it is an invalid request. I have used `Promise.reject()` for throwing error and on successful file generation returning the response `{fileName, filePath}` as Promise from the controller.

```
import express from 'express'
import downloadFile from '../controller/file.controller'

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/file/download/:fileId', (req, res) => {
  downloadFile(req.fileId).then((fileResp) => {
    res.download(fileResp.filePath, fileResp.fileName, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Downloading error')
      } else {
        console.log('Downloading success')
      }
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    res.status(error.status).json({message: error.message})
  })
})
```

I have observed that file is being served on requesting endpoint but it will be empty of size zero bytes.

I have tried the same thing without Promise which works well. In this approach, I have changed my errors from `Promise.reject()` to `throw error` and response from `Promise` to an `object`

```
import express from 'express'
import downloadFile from '../controller/file.controller'

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/file/download/:fileId', (req, res) => {
  const fileResp = downloadFile(req.fileId)
  res.download(fileResp.filePath, fileResp.fileName, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Downloading error')
    } else {
      console.log('Downloading success')
    }
  })
})
```

I am unable to find the issue in the 1st approach. Is it Promise which is causing the issue or I am doing something wrong?